# .NET DI & Multiple Authentication Credentials

Tags: .net, .net-core, dependency-injection, console-application

First of all, I'm new so my apologies if failed to comply with any rules (albeit I've tried to understand them).

I'd greatly appreciate the community help as I'm also new in the .NET world.

I'm building a console app that should automate a bunch of processes. Each process should be independent from each other based on the `appsettings.json` credentials. I'm expecting the automated Foo do some stuff while the automated Bar is doing something else.
So this is my `appsettings.json` at the moment:

```
{
  "ProgramSettings": {
    "ConnectionString": "Server=a; Database=a; User=a; Password=a;",
    "CompanyServer": "https://my.company.server/",
    "Credentials": {
       "Foo": {
          "username": "foouser",
          "password": "foopassword"
       },
       "Bar": {
          "username": "baruser",
          "password": "barpassword"
       }
       // there's a potential to add more credentials in the future
    }
  }
}
```

There is a `ProgramSettings.cs` class:

```
public class ProgramSettings
{
  public string CompanyServer { get; set; }
  public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
  public Dictionary<string, Credential> Credentials { get; set;}
}

public class Credential
{
  public string Username { get; set; }
  public string Password { get; set; }
  // I aim to expand this class to contain more properties in the future
}
```

The I've worked on my `Program.cs`:

```
public class Program
{
  private static string _serverAddress;
  private static Dictionary<string, Credential> _credentials;

  public async Task Main(string[] args)
  {
     IConfiguration configuration = 
         new ConfigurationBuilder()
             .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
             .AddEnvironmentVariables()
             .Build();
     var programSettings = configuration.GetRequiredSection("ProgramSettings").Get<ProgramSettings>();
     _serverAddress = programSettings.CompanyServer;
     _credentials = programsSettings.Credentials;

     var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
     serviceCollection.AddSingleton<ProgramSettings>((isp) => programSettings);
     ConfigureServiceCollection(serviceCollection);

     await serviceCollection.AddSingleton<ProgramService>BuildServiceProvider().GetService<ProgramService>!.Start();
  }

  private static void ConfigureServiceCollection(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
  {
     serviceCollection.AddSingleton<HttpClient>(isp =>
     {
        HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new()
        {
          ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (m, c, c, e) => true
        };
        HttpClient httpClient = new(httpClientHandler)
        {
          BaseAddress = new(_serverAddress)
        };
        return httpClient;
     }

     serviceCollection.AddScoped<CompanyAuthService>();

     // Here comes my problem - how do I do this properly?
     foreach (var credential in _credentials)
     {
       serviceCollection.AddSingleton<SomeController>(isp =>
       {
         var companyService = isp.GetService<CompanyService>();
         var someController = new SomeController(companyService);
         return someController;
       })
       .AddSingleton<SomeOtherController>(isp =>
       {
         var someControllers = isp.GetServices<SomeController>();
         return new SomeOtherController(someControllers);
       })
       .AddScoped<CompanyService>(isp =>
       {
         var httpClient = isp.GetService<HttpClient>();
         var companyAuthService = isp.GetService<CompanyAuthService>();
         var provider = new TokenProvider(companyAuthService, credential.Username, credential.Password);
         return new CompanyService(httpClient, provider);
       });

       serviceCollection.AddScoped<ProgramService>();
     }
  }
}
```

Is it acceptable at all or is there a better way of doing this? The more experienced of you will find out I have problems with my `SomeOtherController` having the same authentication twice. Just bearing in mind one day I may want to include more credentials.

Also, there isn't much code at all at my `ProgramService` function `Start()` hence why I didn't put it in here. There's just a foreach loop getting the hash code of each `SomeOtherController` to see if they are unique to actually start doing some work here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

TL;DR how to do a multiple credential authentication on my Dependency Injection configuration?

How to do a multiple credential authentication on my Dependency Injection configuration